# S3cmd content-encoding gzip not working - always UTF-8 encoding instead

Tags: amazon-s3

I try to upload HTML files to S3 using the S3cmd tools.

```
s3cmd put --recursive --debug --exclude '*' --include '*.html' --mime-type="text/html; charset=utf-8"  --add-header='Content-Encoding: gzip' --add-header='Cache-Control: max-age=259200' foo/ s3://bar/
```

Whatever I try the GZIP encoding does not work. Instead all files on S3 are always encoded this way: Content-Encoding=utf-8

How can I overwrite this utf-8 encoding and how does that happen in the first place? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems it was s3cmd itself. I used version 1.5.0 and that might has a bug. It completely ignored my GZIP content headers. I upgraded to 1.5.2 and now it works fine.